Maximum saved moves to win caused by zugzwang
For a zugzwang where x>y and:

If white has the move, White can force checkmate in x full moves
If Black has the move, White can force checkmate in y full moves

The score of such a zugzwang is x-y. What is the maximum possible score? I know of a position with score 84-25=59.
[Title "WTM wins in 84, BTM loses in 25 "]
[FEN "8/8/8/3k2P1/4pKP1/8/8/8 w - - 0 1"]


I feel the title could be much cleaner,  but it eludes my intuition as to how.

My suggestion is a bit long, but concise, I think.

Is the x+y record known?

8/8/8/8/8/1k2p3/4P3/KN6 (17+28=45) is max for 3-5 men
